# How to connect MySQL server to workbench

Tags: mysql, windows-10, mysql-workbench

[image: Screenshot of MySQL Workbench with no connection to MySQL server]

How do you establish a connection to a running MySQL server from Workbench on Windows? According to the MySQL Installer, it MySQL Server 5.7.20 is installed in Program Files. Upon test connection to localhost, I receive error code 10061: Can't connect to MySQL server on 127.0.0.1

Comment: Workbench is just a client and requires the server component to be running. Where are you running the mysql server? You must configure the connection address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add exception to firewall to allow SQL server service and check. Might be firewall blocking this connection on your system.

Answer (score 0):

select **server** Option From menu bar at top-left corner in MySQL Workbench

[image]

Then click on **StartUpShutdown** Option

[image]

then Click on ***Start Server*** Button

[image]

provide password to localhost server

then your MySQL server will get started